# Type mismatch: expected Integer but was Float

Tags: neo4j

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here. I just copied/pasted a gist and adapt it to my case. (The reference gist is  that given in graphgist : [Movie recommendation](http://gist.neo4j.org/?8173017) )

Here is the gist. [Neo4gist character's recommendation](http://gist.neo4j.org/?f882a981212c2e7b8913)

The failed query is #5. It say's "type mismatch" but I don't know what to do to correct this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reduced the problem down to this failing statement:

```
return reduce(y=0, b in [1,2,3] | y + b^2)
```

The result variable `y` of your `REDUCE` is initialized as a integer. It seems that `b^2` internally creates a float, adding float to int and assigning the value back to a int fails.

There are two ways to work around:

1) initialize the variable as a float:

```
return reduce(y=0.0, b in [1,2,3] | y + b^2)
```

2) convert the result of square manually to a int:

```
return reduce(y=0, b in [1,2,3] | y + toInt(b^2))
```

Comment: so obvious. thank you. but now i have the following error Error: Unknown identifier `xDot`.   I simplify the  request  to this   `MATCH         (pl1)-[x:Rated]->(ch:Charact)<-[y:Rated]-(pl2:Player)
Return   REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.rating) | xDot + a^2)`

Comment: try `MATCH (pl1)-[x:Rated]->(ch:Charact)<-[y:Rated]-(pl2:Player)
WITH collect(x.rating) AS ratings
RETURN reduce(xDot = 0.0, a IN ratings | xDot + a^2)`

Comment: There's actually a 3rd workaround: `reduce(y=0, b in [1,2,3] | y + b*b))` :)